# How to get Device Model in Codeigniter or php

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-agent

I am developing a codeigniter application in which i want to get device model if that application is running in mobile browser else if in computer it will ask to select device model.
How can i get Device Model auto detect in codeigniter application or php
I am using $this->load->library('user_agent')
which is giving me user agent string with  model but how to extract exact model from that string is not good way, string can be anything how to extract device model from there?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, there is no way to know the device model except to trust what the device tells you. But as you pointed out, devices are not required to yield that information.

If you can run javascript on the client, that script can mine more information about the device and return it to you, but you should be aware that devices are more and more reluctant to tell you about themselves. Some browsers running on devices will actively lie to you.

Ultimately, you will never be able to harvest reliable data about the devices using your service, and any advice I could give you today would be thwarted tomorrow.

Edited to add: If you goal is to tailor you views to fit particular devices, then CodeIgniter views are not how you are going to render your UI. It's time to start looking for the JavaScript library that angers you the least.

Comment: Thats not the answer what i am asking for, i am creating an application in which if i execute this app in mobile then there should be device brand and model autodetect via user-agent process,
I am getting proper device model  using $this->load->library('user_agent') but i want to extract only model name from complete string,

Comment: As I mentioned, that information may not be trustworthy, but it you are simply trying to do string manipulations in php, then showing an example string and explaining which part you wish to extract (or multiple examples if the strings vary significantly) or show us what you have already tried, then it will be easier to help you.